# ImageMagick PDF to JPG thumbnails are black

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I have ImageMagick version 6.6.9.7 and using convert for PDF to JPG thumbnails. 
Spaces with no text on the thumbnail are black.

I've installed latest version of GhostScript, tried various methods of fixing (adding -colorspace 'rgb', -flatten, -alpha off, -background white) etc but nothings working.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion would be to reduce the scope of the problem. Try using Ghostscript to convert the PDF to JPEG instead of using ImageMagick. If that works as exepcted then you know the problem is ImageMagick, if it doesn't then you can blame Ghostscript.

gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o out.jpg

If that works then the problem may be in ImageMagick, or it may be the Ghostscript command line which ImageMagick is manufacturing, in which case you'll need to find out what that is, and I can't tell you how to find that out. But try the above and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's solved now. I didn't realise but my php code (written by someone else) had the convert command twice in the script, and it was the other one I had to change to make it work (by adding the -flatten command to convert). Thanks anyway.